# Connecting Aws to local ip ping

Tags: 14.04, aws

I'm able to ping from local machine to aws internal ip through openvpn. But I could not able to ping from aws to local machine ip. How to achieve this.

My Aws has openvpn and client local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please cheak the outbound rules for the aws instance

if not not open please open ssh port for the outbound rule.

Comment: "please open ssh port for the outbound rule." -> How ?

Comment: please cheak security group associated for that instance select that security group then select outbound rule then open ssh port in that

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following.

```
1. Make sure you opened Ping (ICMP) in the Security group(Inbound rule), if you are not enabled try to telnet with opened port, if the telnet is connected then VPN connection established. 
2. Make sure you allowed required the traffic to the Local machine IP in the Security group.
3. Verify routes in the VPC route table.
4. check is there any IP conflict.
5. Is NACL blocking any traffic.
```